# FIXED: Outlook AddIn icon suddenly disappears from interface

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

The icon of our Outlook AddIn application suddenly disappeared from the Outlook interface. Several of our customers with individual Microsoft365 tenants reported the same problem.

We tried re-installing the app by reading the manifest file but that didn't solve the problem.

We cannot find any news with regard to these symptoms on the internet.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
          xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>b5db42d1-a33c-4b2a-9eb8-96f406feeea9</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>2023.03.2.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Softmakers BV</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>nl-NL</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Tim" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Bewaar jouw emails in Tim"/>

  <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://<blurred>.timsaas.com/Tim365/assets/icon-32.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://<blurred>.timsaas.com/Tim365/assets/logo-filled.png"/>

  <!--If you plan to submit this add-in to the Office Store, uncomment the SupportUrl element below-->
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.softmakers.nl" />

  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://login.windows.net</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>  
    <AppDomain>https://timsaas.eu.auth0.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://timsaas.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://<blurred>.timsaas.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://<blurred>.timsaas.com/Tim365/outlook-save"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://<blurred>.timsaas.com/Tim365/outlook-send"/>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

          <!-- Message Read -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

          <!-- Message Compose -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="msgComposeGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneComposeButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageComposeTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

          <!-- Appointment Compose Organizer -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="appComposeGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="appComposeOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneComposeButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="appointmentComposeTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

          <!-- Appointment Compose Attendee -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="appAttendeeGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="appAttendeeButton">
                  <Label resid="paneComposeButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="appointmentComposeTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://<blurred>.timsaas.com/Tim365/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://<blurred>.timsaas.com/Tim365/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://<blurred>.timsaas.com/Tim365/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <!-- <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/function-file/function-file.html"/> -->
        <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://<blurred>.timsaas.com/Tim365/outlook-save"/>
        <bt:Url id="messageComposeTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://<blurred>.timsaas.com/Tim365/outlook-send"/>
        <bt:Url id="appointmentComposeTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://<blurred>.timsaas.com/Tim365/outlook-calr"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="My Add-in Group"/>
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="My Add-in Tab"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Tim Info"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Tim email bewaren"/>
        <bt:String id="paneComposeButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Tim Info"/>
        <bt:String id="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Tim email opstellen"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties. This is an example of a button that opens a task pane."/>
        <bt:String id="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties. This is an example of a button that opens a task pane."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

The text 'blurred' is entered to shield machine names.

Pictures with the icon as it used to be;
https://softmakersbv-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/wilcotroost_softmakers_nl/EsMfp1qbpc9EvvajDRhjta8BfM4BMe-aRZanhFwhWWX7_Q?e=Sx8Bgh

Any help would be more than welcome!

Thanks in advance,
Wilco

Comment: Where do you expect to see the icon in Outlook? Could you be more specific? It also would be great to see the manifest file. Are you able to reproduce the issue with a sample add-in?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Thanks for your time! I added the requested information to the original questiontext.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT The problem is not fixed and the situation remains as described. I did send you the network log.

Comment: @wilcotroost The logs shared is not what we wanted. To collect the logs follow the steps mentioned below:

1. Open outlook web, login to account.  
2. Open developer tools in browser.  
3.  Select network tab and enter 'startupdata' in filter.  
4. Refresh the outlook web page.   
5. You should see a network call and its response starting with 'owaUserConfig' in the tool.
6. Copy the response and share it on mail id shared above.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT  Thanks for your time. The problem seems te be corrected now. The icon appeared again. I guess it took some time to replicatie the fix over all your servers.